# Automate generation of google spreadsheet reports without the use of buttons using google app scripting/javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So, I am trying to automate sending reports to clients without actually pressing a button to the run the script. My vision is this: send reports to clients once a month from my database on its own. I don't want to physically go in everyday and click my "generate report" or "email client" buttons in google spreadsheet. That is every month, I want the database to send reports to clients without me physically pressing a button. I just want to know if that is possible. I have yet to write anything but before I start I need to figure out if this is something that javascript allows you to do. I am just getting into programming since my bachelors is in Metallurgical engineering so this new world of programming seems very daunting, so any advice will help. If you could also guide on where to start, that would be appreciated!

Comment: Automating such a task is actually very easy. If you are learning programming from scratch, the challenge will be to write the script... But if you break apart the problem you'll find plenty of examples and code fragments that will help you. Your brain will have to put all together but that's basically what every brain does !

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend any websites that I can start with. When I google learning JS, it gives me an overwhelming amount of hits and since I dont really know how to code, I need to learn from the basics anyway. Where can I start with the basics and move into some complex later??

Comment: I did learn everything on a forum like this one where we are in , reading the questions that interreted me and eventually googling what was unclear. I read also the Google documentation thoroughly and , believe me I new nothing!. After a couple of weeks I started answering other's questions and after a couple of month... Well, I'm not going to tell the whole story but I did make what I wanted to make, not really the best way but it worked ;).  Maybe you could start with this to see how you feel about it, 
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Comment: Thank you for sharing your story. It helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Something like this should definitely be possible. It looks like Google may already have a chrome extension that would help with this task.

[Google Analytics Extension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)

If that doesn't do it for you, you may have to program a solution yourself, and the Google Sheets API would probably be the best place to start looking.

[Google Sheets API Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/)

Comment: If you want to discourage someone with no programming background this is indeed the best solution.

Comment: Wow, that seems like an ignorant comment. In no way was I discouraging their learning efforts. They asked a question about how to solve a task, and Google seems to have already solved this problem. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is a common programming paradigm, and re-writing code that already exists, while a good learning exercise, is not always the best solution. If they are trying to learn programming, there are also better tasks for beginners to start with

Comment: I was talking about the Google sheet API, which I believe is quite intimidating. No personal offense in any way but an opinion., In other words, a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate generating/sending reports without pressing the button 'run' in Google Apps Script, triggers can help you with this task.

Time-driven (clock) trigger can run script at specified time (for example, every day or every hour).

More information and detailed instruction how to manage triggers manually and programmatically you can find under this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Answer (score -1):

if your data resides in a database then you can use a service like [Cirkulate](https://cirkulate.com), which does exactly this type of database to spreadsheet export in a recurring fashion.

Set a SQL query(or queries), set refresh schedule and add recipients who need to be emailed the spreadsheet. Thats it.

Disclosure: Just to be clear about affiliations, I am the founder of Cirkulate.

Comment: You must *clearly* disclose your affiliation ***in the post*** when linking to your own products or projects. Otherwise, your posts may be treated as “astro-turfing” or spam.